# Ember CLI testing complicated model relationships

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

As far as I can see, when testing ember-data models in ember CLI, all relationships have to be listed in `needs`.  This is fine if the structure is simple, but in many cases there will be multiple layers.

For example, if models are set up with the following relationships defined:

```
Model a:
   belongsTo: b
   belongsTo: c

Model b:
   hasMany: a
   hasMany: d

Model c:
   hasMany: a
   belongsTo: e

Model d:
   hasMany b

Model e:
   hasMany c
```

Then every unit test for any of these models will require every other model listed in `needs`, e.g. A test for `c`:

```
needs: [
    'model:a' // Because c -> a
    'model:e' // Because c -> e
    'model:b' // Because c -> a -> b
    'model:d' // Because c -> a -> b -> d
]
```

My actual configuration is a lot more complicated with 14 models, and each one indirectly related to all the others.

Is my understanding correct?  Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Or is there a good reason for doing it this way that I am missing?

Comment: I just upgraded a project last night to 0.0.46 and noticed this behavior as well, and I don't recall it happening in prior versions.  Could be something new in ember data?

Comment: The issue is being addressed by [this PR](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/2351).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ember default 'Ember-QUnit' then you have to list all the models in needs.

But there is an alternative for testing which I am using i.e. **ember-data-factory-guy**. 
This is used to create factory instead of fixture data when testing Model, component, controller etc.

You can go through it.

https://github.com/danielspaniel/ember-data-factory-guy